# Issues while streaming on MediaPlayer SDK8

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I'm streaming a live radio url directly through Mediaplayer in a service (SDK 8 and above). Some clients are saying that they are hearing some blips and bloops in between the stream. I'm not doing anything different here and just allowing the MediaPlayer to play the audio. Can someone tell me why is this happening?

-Hari

Comment: you should use logcat to debug the operating system and send us the error exactly when the thing occurs.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if it's gonna help, but i can tell you the way i play using http streaming for a mp3, for example:

**1: the code**

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse("http://vprbbc.streamguys.net:80/vprbbc24.mp3"));
mediaPlayer.start();
```

**2: the .pls file**

This URL is from BBC just as an example. It was an .pls file that on linux i downloaded with

```
wget http://foo.bar/file.pls
```

and then i opened with vim (use your favorite editor ;) and i've seen the real URLs inside this file. Unfortunately not all of the .pls are plain text like that.

tested with android 1.6 and 2.2.